# Laravel : Can't Get the view /regions/create

Tags: laravel-5

In my Web.php I have  :

```
Route::get('/regions' , 'RegionsController@show');
Route::get('/regions/{region}' ,'RegionsController@getDetail');
Route::get('/login' , function(){
 return view('users');
});
Route::get('/regions/create',function(){
 return view('/regions/create');

});
Route::get('create',function(){
return view('regions/create');

});
Route::post('/regions' , 'RegionsController@store');

Route::get('users' , function(){
   return view('users');

});
```

But When I want to get the create View , the page is not found , and I know it is due to the GetDetail Method in RegionsController, So my Question is What to do to get the create view when I Type /regions/create ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to switch the placese of routes. Put regions/create before regions/{parameter}

Answer (score 1):

Make folder regions in views folder. Then make file create.blade.php in regions folder.

Comment: Already did that , When I delete Route::get('/regions/{region}' ,'RegionsController@getDetail'); , it works perfectly